# JBoss sar application start service method not called on startup

Tags: jboss, sar

I am attempting to run a JBoss service archive (sar) that was originally running on JBoss 4.2.3.GA to now run on JBoss 6.1.0.Final. I am finding that on the JBoss 6.1.0 startup, the sar's createService method is being called, but not the startService method. There are no errors or exceptions displayed on the console. If I access the jmx-console, I can see that the service state is create (state=6). I can successfully start the service from the jmx-console by manually invoking the start method - the state becomes start (state=3). No errors or exceptions are reported in the console when I do this.

I now stop JBoss and add another sar (let's call it sar 2) which has a dependency on the sar above (sar 1), and then start JBoss. In this case I find that JBoss complains that sar 2 cannot load because it is dependent on sar 1 being in start state but it is in create state. The log snippet is as below. Any insight into differences between JBoss 4.2.3.GA and 6.1.0.Final that would cause this would be appreciated.

```
DEPLOYMENTS MISSING DEPENDENCIES:
  Deployment "quantum:service=dns" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "quantum:service=notificationAgent" (should be in state "Start", but is actually in state "Create")

DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "quantum:service=notificationAgent" is in error due to the following reason(s): Create
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.checkComplete(DeployersImpl.java:1228) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.checkComplete(MainDeployerImpl.java:905) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.checkComplete(MainDeployerPlugin.java:87) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.ProfileDeployerPluginRegistry.checkAllComplete(ProfileDeployerPluginRegistry.java:107) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:135) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:56) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer.startBootstraps(AbstractServer.java:827) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-6]
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer$StartServerTask.run(AbstractServer.java:417) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-6]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [:1.6.0_22]
```